# Install Ubuntu 20.04 along side windows 10 - fail. Forcing Windows 10 To be UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I'm trying to dua boot my laptop (Lenovo thinkPad i7).

1. first I installed Windows 10, on a 100GB partion. left 400GB for later install ubuntu.
2. when installing Ubuntu 20.04, as shown in many manuals/ Videos - the part that you should choose "install alongside window10" does not show in menus, but saying that not no other operation system was detected.

Following one of the [manuals](https://www.itechguides.com/dual-boot-ubuntu-windows-10/) on-line , the part of UEFI (circled in red) does not show. see [image: pic].

What should I do?

Comment: Did you resize partitions on the hard drive? You should be able to do it from the Windows utility called Disk Management. See https://www.diskgenius.com/how-to/resize-partition-windows-10.php Make sure you also turn off Legacy Boot or Secure Boot when you install Linux.

Comment: @Jeff I left a designated partion for it.

Comment: UEFI is what replaced "BIOS" a decade ago. So, you can always access it before loading any OS with a specific dedicated key. Now, that not showing up in Windows advanced options probably means you installed Windows in Legacy/"BIOS" mode and are now booting the Ubuntu installer in the proper UEFI mode and/or have Fast Startup enabled.

Comment: Unpartitionated space is NOT a partition. You can't create useful partitions to install Ubuntu from Windows.

Comment: Another thing that you can do is just select "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu", and choose partition sizes yourself when you are in the partitioner (an Ubiquity installer thing) and reinstall Windows. Make sure you get your product key first so that you can restore the Windows version without purchasing a new product key (after you install Ubuntu)

Comment: @ChanganAuto As said, I created a partion for it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto How do I force windows to install at UEFi and not Legacy as happend?

Comment: If you did then you did it wrong because you CAN'T.

Comment: Open UEFI settings and disable Legacy/CSM. This assures the installer boots and installs in the correct mode. Also make sure the target drive is GPT because that's a Windows requirement.

Comment: @guyd You can disable Legacy Boot in your BIOS settings. If you look up the BIOS for your system (you can find it by doing a Google Search with syntax including the brand and model of your computer), you should be able to figure out how to access the settings.

Comment: @Jeff Actually I was saying that unallocated space is what you should have to install Ubuntu, not a partition, because the types of partitions required by Linux cannot be created in Windows. But shrinking one or more to leave room for Ubuntu can and should be done from Windows using Windows native tools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: @ChanganAuto Oh, my bad. I should have thought of that. I have done dual-boots tons of times and I should have known that.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the guided "Install Alongside Windows" option, all of the following must be true:

1. **You need viable bootable Ubuntu installation media**. In order to confirm this, you must verify the integrity of the downloaded ISO by comparing checksums. You must also verify the integrity of the flash.
2. **You need enough unpartitioned free space for Ubuntu**. The minimum system requirement for Ubuntu is 25GB.  Do not create a partition for Ubuntu.  It must be **unpartitioned free space**.  The installer will create partitions for you.
3. **You must boot the USB using the same UEFI or Legacy/BIOS method in which Windows is already installed**. Windows is generally installed as a UEFI operating system, so you must boot the USB as a UEFI disk. If you're not sure how to do this, you must read the documentation for your motherboard. Booting a USB is a function of your hardware and not any other operating system. Different motherboards have different interfaces, so you have to figure out the booting process for your particular hardware.

If you need a general reference for creating bootable media and installing Ubuntu, please refer to the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop).

Comment: Should I define whem using RUFUS, that UEFI is needed ?

Comment: @guyd the official tutorial recommends etcher, which doesn't confuse users with a lot options that aren't needed just for the simple task of making bootable installation media. Media made with etcher can be booted as either UEFI or legacy. If you want to use rufus, then you need to make sure that the options you choose are appropriate for the USB you want to create

Comment: OK. Since when in BIOS I setup that only UEFI is possible to boot, USB stick with Windows 10 setup, didn't boot up. So I figured out that leave BIOS setup as "BOTH" (legacy & UEFI) is inconclusive and ended with Windows as "Legacy"

Comment: I can't give any advice on a Windows 10 USB. If you want help with a Windows USB, please ask on Super User.  I do know that MS does not condone any application for flashing USB installation media except its own proprietary media creation tool.

Comment: OK. I'm trying to find out what caused Windows 10 to be installed as "Legacy", is BIOS was set to "BOTH"

Comment: I don't know.  Is your hard drive formatted with a GPT partition scheme? If you are using MBR partitioning, you can't install a UEFI operating system there. You're also limited to 4 partitions which is overly restrictive for a dual boot configuration.

Comment: During Windows installation, all partiotns were erased, and 3 new ones were created: Windows, Ubuntu, communal partition. Is that GPT ?

Comment: Not necessarily.  You'd need to format the entire disk to change the partition scheme. You can do this in an Ubuntu live session using the Disks app and it forces you to choose GPT or MBR

Comment: Wow, that I did'nt know. Great :)

Answer (score 0):

**To sum up all coments and answers given that sovled my case:**

1. Partion table - GPT is for UEFI and MBR is for BIOS
2. BIOS setup - set **UEFI** where needed (and not **Legacy**). Make sure boot will be from *UEFI* based only (where **BOTH** is option(Legacy and UEFI), make sure to select **UEFI**.
3. HDD partion - prior to any OS installation, use ubuntu's on-stick USB installation, to delete all partions. make sure to create a file parttion table- **GPT** (using **gPart**).
4. Windows installtion - It is recommended to start with windows installtion and only after, Ubnutu. Use **Rufus** to create a bootable windows installtion. MAKE sure to select **GPT** in rufus's menu to also create Windwos installation **UEFI** (as said in section **2** - we are forcing all installation and BIOS setups to use UEFI).
5. After Windows installtion - Check **MSINFO**, that result is **UEFI** and not **Legacy**.
6. Ubuntu's installation. -Is Windows was installed as UEFI, **ONLY THEN** you'll get **Install Ubntu alongside Windows** at first steps of Ubuntu's installtion.

GOOD LUCK
guy